# save google forms response to a mysql database

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this html file for the google form and would like to store form response in a mysql database. As of now I am storing my form response to a google sheet and copying this data to a mysql table. Now I want my results stored directly stored in the database.

```
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <b>Add Record</b><br />

    <form>
    First name: <input id="firstname" name="firstName" type="text" /> <br />

    Last name: <input id="lastname" name="lastName" type="text" /> <br />

    DOB: <input id="dob" name="dob" type="date" /> <br />

    Email: <input id="email" name="email type="text" /> <br />

    Phone: <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" /> <br />

   <input onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Add Row" /> <br />

   <input onclick="google.script.host.close()" type="button" value="Exit" />
   </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function formSubmit() {
            google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
        }
    </script>
</html>


    function getData(){
   var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
   var formResponse = formResponses[i];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      var firstName = itemResponse.getResponse(),
      lastName = itemResponse.getResponse(),
      dob = itemResponse.getResponse(),
      email = itemResponse.getResponse(),
      phone = itemResponse.getResponse(),
      insertFormData = copyDataToTable(firstName, lastName, dob, email, phone);
}


 function copyDataToTable(firstName, lastName, dob, email, phone) 
 {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO myTable (firstName, lastName, dob, email, phone) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  stmt.setString(1, firstName);
  stmt.setString(2, lastName);
  stmt.setString(3, dob);
  stmt.setString(4, email);
  stmt.setString(5, phone);
  stmt.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)'s [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) and [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

Form Service

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Forms.

JDBC

> Apps Script can connect to external databases through the [JDBC service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc), a wrapper around the standard J[ava Database Connectivity technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html). In Apps Script, the JDBC service supports [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/), MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases.

Using Form service you can use the [**`getItemResponses()`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getItemResponses())method to get all item responses.

> Gets all item responses contained in this form response, in the same order as the items appear in the form. **If the form response does not contain a response for a given TextItem, DateItem, TimeItem, or ParagraphTextItem, the ItemResponse returned for that item will have an empty string as the response.If the form response omits a response for any other item type, this method will exclude that item from its returned array**.

Then use those responses as data to be entered in the database.

Sample Code

```
// Write one row of data to a table.
function writeOneRecord() {
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO entries '
+ '(guestName, content) values (?, ?)');
stmt.setString(1, 'First Guest');
stmt.setString(2, 'Hello, world');
stmt.execute();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Updated my original post, but looks like I am not setting the response right to the variable.